# How to check if a string contain a list if characters which are not in english

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I want to valid textbox text. the textbox is for a phone number so, of course, letters and anything other the number I used different kinds of code

ex

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sub").click(function () {
            var regex = /[$%^&*()_+[]{}<>?]אבגדהוזחטיכךלמםנןסעפצקרשת  \"/
            var bleangth = $('.bphone').val().length;
            var eleangth = $('.ephone').val().leangth;
            var cbphone = $('.bphone').val();
            var cephone = $('.ephone').val();
            if (bleangth < 3 || eleangth < 7) {
                $('#bad').removeClass("error");
                $('#short').addClass("error");

            }
            else
                if (regex.test(cbphone) || regex.test(cephone)) {
                    $('#short').removeClass("error");
                    $('#bad').addClass("error");
                }
                else {
                    $('#bad').removeClass("error");
                    $('#short').removeClass("error");
                    //$('h3').removeClass("snerror")
                }
            alert( "end " + regex.test(cephone) +" start " + regex.test(cbphone));
        });
```

As you see I entered letters from different language but for some reason the code can't "read" it and return true is there a way maybe to get string split it to array and then use it? or different code or something I need to add/ download

Thank you in advance

Comment: please add some examples to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You mean jsfiddle? or a photo?

Comment: just test cases in text is fine.

Comment: I'll try my best

so the textbox is inside a form and whenever the user presses the submit button code will run and check all the charters inside the textbox and if everything is good it will continue and if not an error message will pop up.

as I said it's for a phone number so the code needs to check for:

a)length of the number(that work)

b)that only number are entered without letters 
the code I entered do it fine for English letters but fail on any other language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make regular expression with unicode value

```
var regex = /^[\u05d0-\u05ea]|[$%^&*()_+{}<>\]\[?]$/
```

Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var regex = /^[\u05d0-\u05ea]|[$%^&*()_+{}<>\]\[?]$/
    $("#buttonCheck").click(function(){
            alert(regex.test($("#text").val()));
  });
});
```

[Example Link](https://jsfiddle.net/02v39a4a/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If requirement is for only numbers to be input you should be able to use `NOT` operator `!` operator with `RegExp` `/\D/` ; e.g.; `!/\D/.test(/*input*/)` where `true` would be result if input is a digit, `false` if input is not a digit.

---

An approach using `HTML5` `<input>` element with `pattern` attribute set to `\d+`, `required` attribute; `<label>` element, `CSS` `:focus`, `:invalid` , adjacent siblings selector `+`

```css
input + label {
  display:none;
}

input:focus:invalid + label {
  display:block;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" 
       pattern="\d+"
       placeholder="Please input digits 0-9"
       required /><label>Invalid input. Please input digits 0-9</label>
```

Comment: Yes only numbers are required but I want whenever one of those characters are entered that error message will show up

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use `if..else` to achieve this. _"but I want whenever one of those characters are entered"_ Your handler is at `click` event, not `input` event? Simplest approach would be to use `HTML5` `pattern` attribute, `css`

Comment: Sorry wasn't clear I'm not looking for onkey event looking for on submit event the button press press event is for the submit button

Comment: The message should appear only when submit button is clicked? Is `HTM5` ,  `CSS` approach a possible solution? You may need to map hebrew characters to numeric literal characters

Comment: I dont care when the message appear it can also be on blur I don't know how to check / block characters in HTML5 or CSS but if you know how to do it maybe it can also work.

Comment: Are only hebrew characters at `RegExp` at Question and numeric literals valid input? Note also, `RegExp` at Question also appears to include space character

Comment: The only valid input is numbers I want it for a phone number textbox but I need to block all of the characters inside the regexp

Comment: Im sorry didnt fully understood the pattern thing how by only typing \d+ you make all English letters unveiled?

Comment: @saarsc `\d+` sets validity pattern for `input` element to digit characters 0-9. If user input is not 0-9 error message is displayed.